# How to make vim position the cursor with custom mapping for <C-LeftMouse>?

Tags: key-bindings, cursor, mouse

I am using vim 8.2 in terminal with mouse support (mouse=a) and trying to define a custom mapping for <C-LeftMouse>. The mapping itself works but the problem is that vim stops setting cursor position at the mouse click with Ctrl button pressed.

Specifically, I map <C-LeftMouse> to a command that adds the word under cursor to the search history and highlights it. After clicking, the cursor position will not change and the highlighted word will be one at the old cursor position. So, I have to first do <LeftMouse> click to change the cursor position and then <C-LeftMouse> to execute my command with the new position.

I tried mapping my command to <C-LeftRelease> but in that case <C-LeftMouse> is kept mapped to the default action ("CTRL-]") which leads to jumping to a tag if it is found.

I thought about writing a function to position the cursor and execute my custom command but I am afraid it may be not trivial (I would like also to be able to click to a different window, as in the default behavior).

Is there a way to keep vim positioning the cursor automatically after assigning commands to mouse events?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say for example that you are talking about the `*N` command for the custom bit. Then the following should work:

```
nnoremap <C-LeftMouse> <LeftMouse>*N
```

(when I tried this it worked perfectly). The idea is to delegate to the default `<LeftMouse>` behavior, which does everything you want.

Comment: brilliant! This works really for me. Though, what if <LeftMouse> was mapped to something custom as well? I am just curious to know this for future possible cases.

Comment: That would not be a problem. The `noremap` versions of the `map` commands ensure that all key sequences on the rhs retain their original meaning and do not use any custom remappings of these key sequences.

Comment: @MaximV. as Ingo points out, that is why we use a non-recursive mapping. Rarely, recursive mappings are actually desired (most often with `<Plug>` mappings); for that, omit `nore`.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, there is the following minor problem with this solution: after I press <C-LeftMouse> my custom command is executed successfully but then Ctrl key seems to be not marked as released in vim (though, it is not physically pressed anymore); therefore, if I start scrolling with mouse wheel, it scrolls pages, not lines. I have to press <LeftMouse> again to reset the state. Can this be overcome somehow?

Comment: Update: the minor problem with Ctrl key not marked as released seems to be not related to the solution from the answer. After unmapping <C-LeftMouse> I observed the same behavior. Is this a feature? Can it be avoided?

Comment: @MaximV. hm i'm experiencing this too. Sounds like a bug to me; I would file that at https://github.com/vim/vim

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, the problem with scrolling is solved for vim 9: [d6212b8](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/d6212b80d6d49d4d890c3141b7c6b83f899333b0)